# How to use fontconfig to get font list (C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, truetype

I hear that fontconfig is the best option for getting fonts in linux. Unfortunately, I've been looking through their developer documentation and I have absolutely no clue what I'm doing. It would appear there is no simple function to get a list of system fonts. I have to perform a pattern search instead... right?

In short, what is the best way to get a list of true-type fonts (their family, face, and directory) with fontconfig? Of course, if there's something better than fontconfig, I'm certainly open to other solutions.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar question, and found this post (the fontconfig documentation is a little difficult to get through).  MindaugasJ's response was useful, but watch out for the extra lines calling things like `FcPatternPrint()` or printing out the results of `FcNameUnparse()`.  In addition, you need to add a `FC_FILE` argument to the list of arguments passed to `FcObjectSetBuild`.  Something like this:

```
FcConfig* config = FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts();
FcPattern* pat = FcPatternCreate();
FcObjectSet* os = FcObjectSetBuild (FC_FAMILY, FC_STYLE, FC_LANG, FC_FILE, (char *) 0);
FcFontSet* fs = FcFontList(config, pat, os);

printf("Total matching fonts: %d\n", fs->nfont);
for (int i=0; fs && i < fs->nfont; ++i) {
   FcPattern* font = fs->fonts[i];
   FcChar8 *file, *style, *family;
   if (FcPatternGetString(font, FC_FILE, 0, &file) == FcResultMatch &&
       FcPatternGetString(font, FC_FAMILY, 0, &family) == FcResultMatch &&
       FcPatternGetString(font, FC_STYLE, 0, &style) == FcResultMatch)
   {
      printf("Filename: %s (family %s, style %s)\n", file, family, style);
   }
}
if (fs) FcFontSetDestroy(fs);
```

I had a slightly different problem to solve in that I needed to find the font file to pass to freetype's `FC_New_Face()` function given some font "name".  This code is able to use fontconfig to find the best file to match a name:

```
FcConfig* config = FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts();

// configure the search pattern, 
// assume "name" is a std::string with the desired font name in it
FcPattern* pat = FcNameParse((const FcChar8*)(name.c_str()));
FcConfigSubstitute(config, pat, FcMatchPattern);
FcDefaultSubstitute(pat);

// find the font
FcResult res;
FcPattern* font = FcFontMatch(config, pat, &res);
if (font)
{
   FcChar8* file = NULL;
   if (FcPatternGetString(font, FC_FILE, 0, &file) == FcResultMatch)
   {
      // save the file to another std::string
      fontFile = (char*)file;
   }
   FcPatternDestroy(font);
}

FcPatternDestroy(pat);
```

Comment: There is typo in your code: FcChar8* file, style, family;
You forgot to add * for style and family. Segfaults.

Comment: Thank you both for your code guys, but when I ran this I got run-time assertion. output: "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in test-fontconfig.exe."

Comment: @codekiddy replace the FcFontMatch line by:
FcResult result = FcResultNoMatch;
FcPattern* font = FcFontMatch(config, pat, &result);

Comment: typo: `FC_New_Face`, you probebly meant `FT_New_Face`

Comment: Your second Code example is illegal, as it passes a NULL Pointer in `FcFontMatch(config, pat, NULL)`, which will be dereferend and written to. Assertions are made in the debug version of fontconfig, but not in the release builds. Please address this issue! https://cgit.freedesktop.org/fontconfig/tree/src/fcmatch.c#n779

Comment: See the comment from @FolkertvanHeusden

Comment: In your first example, you should call FcObjectSetDestroy, FcPatternDestroy, FcConfigDestroy, no ?

Answer (score 7):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but it will give you the list of fonts available.

```
#include <fontconfig.h>

FcPattern *pat;
FcFontSet *fs;
FcObjectSet *os;
FcChar8 *s, *file;
FcConfig *config;
FcBool result;
int i;

result = FcInit();
config = FcConfigGetCurrent();
FcConfigSetRescanInterval(config, 0);

// show the fonts (debugging)
pat = FcPatternCreate();
os = FcObjectSetBuild (FC_FAMILY, FC_STYLE, FC_LANG, (char *) 0);
fs = FcFontList(config, pat, os);
printf("Total fonts: %d", fs->nfont);
for (i=0; fs && i < fs->nfont; i++) {
    FcPattern *font = fs->fonts[i];//FcFontSetFont(fs, i);
    FcPatternPrint(font);
    s = FcNameUnparse(font);
    if (FcPatternGetString(font, FC_FILE, 0, &file) == FcResultMatch) {
        printf("Filename: %s", file);
    }
    printf("Font: %s", s);
    free(s);
}
if (fs) FcFontSetDestroy(fs);
```

Comment: is there a command line equivalent?