# Must I use path to fonts?

Tags: c++, x11, freetype

The [FT_New_Face](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_New_Face) function seems to be the one I'm looking for, but it requires a path to the font file. I would like to open a font like "Times New Roman," without supplying a path. How can I do that?

Comment: You could wrap FT_New_Face into a function accepting font name rather than path. The path(s) this function would read from a settings file indicating the search paths where fonts could be found. Since you wouldn't want to read your paths over and over again, make it stateful by making it a functor (object with overloaded ()) or a method of e.g. a FontFinder class.

Comment: "Times New Roman" is the font *name*, but it is not the name of the font *file*. The name string is inside the font file. So how would FreeType know what font file to select when you give it only a name? You need a translation from font name to font file *somewhere* in your code.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: How to find the font on disk? I see some fonts located in `/usr/share/fonts` in my Ubuntu installation, is that where I should look in all distros? How do I find out the system default fonts?

Comment: @RadLexus: That's what I'm asking about. A good font system would use font names, as that's what most users of the API wants. Only a flawed API would require the user to supply system dependent and -internal paths (or even worse: old-school apps where each app has it's own set of fonts). I was hoping for a better function call I had missed. In the spirit of X and friends it's all about *not* pushing anything on the subsystems/coders, which means pushing all the work to the app developers. That's why I find GNU so bad and Linux so good, and always wishing for a BDFL to clean up their act.

Comment: Ah - and it looks like even for Ubuntu it's not that straightforward ... "There are various locations in GNU/Linux in which fonts can be kept. [list of possible folders]" at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most unix-based systems use [Fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) for this to get best matching font file from set of search parameters ( family name, variations, weight etc )

> Fontconfig is a library for configuring and customizing font access.
>
> **Fontconfig can:**
>
> - discover new fonts when installed automatically, removing a common
>     source of configuration problems.
> - perform font name substitution, so that appropriate alternative fonts can be selected if fonts are missing.
> - identify the set of fonts required to completely cover a set
>     of languages.
> - have GUI configuration tools built as it uses an XML-based configuration file (though with autodiscovery, we believe
>     this need is minimized).
> - efficiently and quickly find the fonts you
>     need among the set of fonts you have installed, even if you have
>     installed thousands of fonts, while minimzing memory usage.
> - be used in concert with the X Render Extension and FreeType to implement high quality, anti-aliased and subpixel rendered text on a display.
>
> **Fontconfig does not:**
>
> - render the fonts themselves (this is left to FreeType or other
>     rendering mechanisms)
> - depend on the X Window System in any fashion, so
>     that printer only applications do not have such dependencies

Fontconfig is relatively portable and used on a variety of systems, however OSX has [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) which has similar functionality and Windows has [DirectWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx)

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542832/how-to-use-fontconfig-to-get-font-list-c-c) question for help on how to use Fontconfig.