# Fontconfig: cannot find application font

Tags: c, truetype, fontconfig

I imitated the code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542832/how-to-use-fontconfig-to-get-font-list-c-c), except that I wanted to add support for local fonts, so the code was adapted like this.

```
FcConfig* config = FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts();
FcConfigAppFontAddDir(config, (FcChar8*) "../fonts");
FcConfigSubstitute(config, pat, FcMatchPattern);
FcDefaultSubstitute(pat);

FcStrList* dirs = FcConfigGetFontDirs(config);
FcChar8* current;
while ((current = FcStrListNext(dirs)) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", (char*) current);

FcResult res;
FcPattern* font = FcFontMatch(config, pat, &res);
if (font)
{
   FcChar8* file = NULL;
   if (FcPatternGetString(font, FC_FILE, 0, &file) == FcResultMatch)
   {
      printf("%s\n", (char*) file);
   }
   FcPatternDestroy(font);
}

FcPatternDestroy(pat);
FcStrListDone(dirs);
```

However, I found the following situation:

- A `.uuid` file appears in `fonts` directory, meaning that the directory (along with font files in it) is correctly found.
- The printed directories does not contain my custom directory.
- Even when I am referencing a font that I put into the custom directory and does not exist in system font directories, the system cannot find it, and instead a fallback font (Noto Sans CJK) is matched instead.

---

**Update:**
The fonts can only be referenced through font name as opposed to file name. Case closed.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The fonts can only be referenced through font name as opposed to file name. Case closed.